# Randomly created answer draft after edit

Tags: bug, draft

I was browsing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471020/javascript-split-without-losing-first-element-not-regex), when I decided I should edit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19471095/908879) because he used `"...;"` instead of `"...";` among other improvements that could be done, then after a series of things I did (don't remember exactly in which order) **I noticed I had a draft for posting the answer that I edited before.**

The events I did while in the page are the following:

- clicked the question score to see the up/down votes
- posted a comment on the question
- clicked (see more comments)
- clicked (see new answer)
- posted a comment on the answer
- edited my comment on the answer
- deleted my comment
- edited the answer
- clicked (see new answer of other guy)
- scrolled down and I saw the draft of an answer I allegedly typed with the exact same words of the answer I edited
- discarded the draft
- realized I should have paid attention whether the draft contained the outdated answer or the updated one

**Notes:** I am using FireFox 24.0 and the order of events might not be 100% accurate.

I know is not a big bug, but someone could accidentally post it (and they will think he tried to steal his answer). Also I am not sure where drafts are stored, but it is unnecessary space wasted.

Comment: Can you replicate with the repro steps you provided and an empty cache and especially empty local storage?

Comment: @Sklivvz I haven't tried to replicate it as it will be kind of hard to do it with valid edits/comments/wait for new answers to appear at the right time/etc, also I have a headache because there was a PUF in my laptop and gray smoke came out of it and I accidentally smell it more than I should, I disconnected the laptop immideatly and managed to make a backup but I want to go to sleep right now (and this was after the bug, so don't think I could hallucinated it) edit: there was a big spark on the side where USB ports are, I am really worried

Comment: This comes up for me all the time, across many versions of Firefox, seemingly at random. I'll have to pay close attention to what I'm doing in case it happens again.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn is there a `status-sometimesrepro`? I really don't like my question to be tagged as `status-norepro`

Comment: Yeahhhhh I just reproed it again.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Seriously? Typing "reproduced" is too much work, but "Yeahhhhh" is OK?? If you're really too tired to type, you can always omit the redundant "again" - it's in the "re" already :-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: "Seriously?" Not very, as you can tell :P

Comment: ajax333221 and @BoltClock, does it also overwrite existing drafts? That would be a bigger problem to me than the space that might be wasted.

Comment: @Arjan: Not sure.